What is the correct way to set the value of a field in a struct in a Flatbuffers message via reflection?
I haven't found a lot of information about how to (correctly) set a field from a struct inside a Flatbuffers message using the reflection functionality.
I saw that there's the following function in the reflection.h file:
// Set any struct field as a 64bit int, regardless of type what it is.
inline void SetAnyFieldI(Struct *st, const reflection::Field &field,
                         int64_t val)

This takes as argument a Struct *.
Then there's this function that you can use to get a Struct field, but this returns a const Struct* so I can't actually use it in combination with the function above:
// Get a field, if you know it's a struct.
inline const Struct *GetFieldStruct(const Table &table,
                                    const reflection::Field &field)

Then I saw that there's also the following function:
template<typename T>
T *GetAnyFieldAddressOf(const Table &table, const reflection::Field &field) {
  return reinterpret_cast<T *>(table.GetAddressOf(field.offset()));
}

but because it takes as argument consts, this needs to also return a const Struct* so that I don't get a compiling error.
I can do the cast myself to obtain the non-const Struct as follows:
// bufFb is the buffer containing the message
flatbuffers::Table* fbRoot = flatbuffers::GetAnyRoot(bufFb);
const reflection::Field* fbFieldContent = fbSchemaRoot->fields()->LookupByKey("content");
flatbuffers::Struct* structContent = reinterpret_cast<flatbuffers::Struct*>((*fbRoot).GetAddressOf((*fbFieldContent).offset()));

However, I am wondering if I should really do this, since all the internal functions point towards the direction that maybe you shouldn't return a non-const Struct, and hence that you maybe shouldn't set the fields of the Struct.
Is that so or is it fine to use the last piece of code? What are the caveats in doing so? (Assuming, still, that you take care to correctly set the inner fields of the struct.)
Thank you!
